# Making a customized Geo Node function for resampling a curve (Editted, new setup and new problem!)

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

So, I am creating a modifier for haircards placement and I would love to have a way to properly resample a curve with a fixed number of points and adaptive distancing between them according to the points angle. I tried a ton of different ways to make it work, with varying degress of success.

This is my current setup:

[image]

What you see in the image is exactly what I want. **HOWEVER**, when I move the handle to either side, the effect gets a bias to either side, as can be seen in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciNtLmMyMrY

.blend file: [image]

If anyone's curious, I have a demo of a prototype for this tool, which works but... it's very unreliable, I want to do it properly, for which I need to work on this matter.

https://youtu.be/b5M8qGQkV8U